# Problems with radiobutton in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following problem with radiobuttons in angular. The ng-change directive doesn't seems to run. Event on change on elements works.

HTML code

```
<div class="radio" ng-repeat="app in appUsed">
            <label for="<% app %>">
                <input type="radio"
                       id="<% app %>"
                       name="app"
                       ng-change="$parent.clear()"
                       ng-value="<% app %>"
                       ng-model="$parent.results['psi']['app_version']">
                <% app %>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio"
                       id="other"
                       name="app"
                       ng-value='other'
                       ng-model="results['psi']['app_version']"
                       ng-change="enableOther()}"
                       > Other:
                <input type ='text' id="otherAppValue" ng-model="otherRadioValue" ng-disabled="!otherRadioFlag">
            </label>
        </div>
```

The angular brackets was replaced with <% %> because I work with laravel.

Here's JS fragment. I want them to console sth if the button changes.

```
$scope.clear = function () {
// $scope.clear = function() {
    console.log('lalala');
   // $scope.otherRadioFlag = false;
  //  $scope.otherRadioValue = "";
}
$scope.enableOther = function() {

    console.log('ssadasds');
 //   $scope.otherRadioFlag = true;
   // console.log($scope.otherRadioFlag);
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: why you call clear function with $parent.clear?

Comment: Remove $parent from your ng-model as it's an object.

Comment: It's an advice from similar topic on stack, when I remove it still doesn't work

Comment: Remove **}** from **ng-change="enableOther()}"**

Comment: this is not the case either, it is remain after my experiments, still doesn't work